# Showing only text ads in adMob

Tags: android, admob

I have updated my adMob account to new version. I want to show only text ads in my apps. How can I do that with new version of adMob account ??

or, how can I block image ads in new version of adMob account ????

Answer (score 4):

This can be done on your AdMob account. Go to:

AdMob -> Monetize -> *Select your app* -> *Select your ad unit*

Here you can choose which "Ad type" you want to use. You want to uncheck "Image" and "Video" and keep "Text" checked.

Comment: Have you had any luck this this? Have you seen an increase by removing text ads?