# how can i only show text ads in adMob

Tags: javascript, jquery, admob, ads

I wanna show only text ads in my Android apps. How can I force Admob to only show text ads?

The solution provided here [Showing only text ads in adMob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115454/showing-only-text-ads-in-admob/64079024#64079024) is not working any more on the current version of AdMob. there is only 2 ad type "Video" & "Text - Image" unfortunately i can uncheck video but not image. The question now is how to do it by coding? is there any code to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115454/showing-only-text-ads-in-admob

Comment: the solution provided is not working any more on the current version of AdMob.
there is only 2 ad type "Video" & "Text - Image" unfortunately i can uncheck video but not image. The question now is how to do it by coding? is there any code to do that?